# Keeping an item toggled off after refresh/change of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could i keep a div hidden after the user goes to another page or refreshes the page? I have the following code in the footer so it loads on every page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#clickmebottom').click(function() {
      $('#bottomfixtab').animate({
           height: 'toggle'
           }, 350
      );
 });
});
```

#clickmebottom is an X button that - on click - hides the #bottomfixtab div (small fixed banner at bottom of screen)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Take a look at cookies: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a jQuery plugin such as [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to simplify cookie access. So your code would become something like this to save the div's toggle setting:

```
// pseudo-code, you'll want to check the actual syntax
$(document).ready(function() {

  // see if the cookie is set, if it is, hide the div
  if ( $.cookie('toggledDiv' ) {
    $('#bottomfixtab').hide();
  }
  $('#clickmebottom').click(function() {
    $.cookie('toggledDiv');
    $('#bottomfixtab').animate({
      height: 'toggle'
    }, 350 );
  });
});
```

this will probably make the div flash then hide so if you want to avoid that flash, set the default to display: none, then if the cookie is *not* set, show the div:

```
// again, pseduo-code
if ( !$.cookie('toggledDiv') ) {
  $('#bottomfixtab').show()
}
```